# Change the behavior of a function when the point is in a table

Tags: org-table, functions

How can I change the behavior of a function when the point is in an org-table? Is there a function like "table-p" that returns true when the point is in a table (like region-active-p returns true when a region is selected)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> org-at-table-p is a compiled Lisp function in ‘org.el’.
>
> `(org-at-table-p &optional TABLE-TYPE)`
>
> Return t if the cursor is inside an org-type table.
> If TABLE-TYPE is non-nil, also check for table.el-type tables.